# Filtering documents by objects in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array of strings in my schema, and I'm trying to filter documents depending on their arrays containing certain strings or not. Below is my schema, where the ingredients array is what I'm trying to filter by:

```
const foodSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  ingredients: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
  ],
});
```

In nodejs, I have the following inside my express router:

```
router.get('/food', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const match = {};

  if (req.query.name) {
    match.name = req.query.name;
  }

  if (req.query.ingredients) {
    match.ingredients = req.query.ingredients;
  }

  try {
    const allFood = await Food.find(match);
    res.send({
      allFood,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

Here's an example request being sent:

```
{{url}}/food?ingredients=Salmon Meal&ingredients=Deboned Turkey
```

I would expect to get all food documents where their ingredients array contain both Salmon Meal and Deboned Turkey, but I always get an empty array. The casing is correct. If I just use one ingredient in the query, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$all`

```
match.ingredients = { $all: req.query.ingredients };
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$in`

```
if (req.query.ingredients && req.query.ingredients.length > 0) {
  match.ingredients = { $in: req.query.ingredients };
}
```

Comment: That returns all food objects where either Salmon Meal or Deboned Turkey is an ingredient. OP asked for a way to get all food objects where both Salmon Meal AND Deboned Turkey are ingredients.

Comment: Vuza is correct, but your answer helps me with another task I was trying to complete. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I was still able to help.